# Provide raw data in og:image open graph meta tag

Tags: javascript, qr-code, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I know it's possible to provide an absolute URL as the content for `og:image` graph meta tag.

However, I have some pages without a picture, but a generated qr code only representing a Lightning Network invoice.

Is it possible to provide it as raw data in the `og:image` tag as I do in the page body?

Something like:

```js
meta: [
  {
    name: 'og:image',
    content: 'data:image/png;base64,iVR...YII='
  }
]
```